# Match '$' Symbol in regex

Tags: php, regex

I have the following expression:

```
"MSRP | <span style='text-decoration: line-through;'>$74,660</span><br /> Buy | $67,092
```

I need

```
MSRP $74,600 $67,092
```

I can't seem to find the regex to include the '$' symbol in the match group. This is what I am currently doing:

```
MSRP | <[^>]+>\$([^>]+)<[^>]+> *<[^>]+> *Buy | $([^>]+)\/i
```

What is wrong with this expression and why is it not including the '$' symbol?

Comment: Escape the pipes using \| as they are special characters.

Comment: ^^ This and escape the second dollar sign as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `$` and `|` and also put the `\$`inside the parenthesis to match in a group:

```
(MSRP) \| <[^>]+>(\$[^>]+)<[^>]+> *<[^>]+> *Buy \| (\$[^>]+)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the $ sign together with the numbers in your results, you need to put it into the parenthesis:

Here is a working example with PHP:

```
$str = "MSRP | <span style='text-decoration: line-through;'>$74,660</span><br /> Buy | $67,092";
preg_match('/MSRP \| <[^>]+>(\$[^>]+)<[^>]+> *<[^>]+> *Buy \| (\$[^>]+)/i', $str, $matches);
```

I got the results like this:

```
 1 => '$74,660', 2 => '$67,092'
```